# Postgresql restore dump via psql got 'permission denied for table'

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, pg-restore

I have database backup in format: dump.sql.gz (and `chmod 777` on it)

I need to restore in another server

I logged via postgres and:

```
createdb newdb
gunzip < dump.sql.gz | psql newdb
```

All is going well, but at one moment I got this errors:

```
SET
SET
SET
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
SET
SET
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE SEQUENCE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
...
ALTER TABLE
CREATE INDEX
...
GRANT
GRANT
ERROR:  permission denied for table categories
ERROR:  permission denied for table categories
ERROR:  permission denied for table categories
...
```

And after it restoring ends.

**UPDATE:**

```
from TOC entry 14923; 0 703831 MATERIALIZED VIEW DATA view_products myuser
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  permission denied for table categories
Command was: REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW public.view_products;
```

What's going wrong?
Please help

Comment: You are not running `psql` with as database user with sufficient privileges to create table categories. Since you did not supply ` -U some_name` `psql` will run as the system user in effect where you ran the command. Use `-U super_user` to the command where super_user is  replaced with a database user with sufficient privileges.

Comment: You have to figure out the statement that creates the first error and debug that.